# A synonym for "picky" with a positive connotation (food)?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> We're very **picky** about the ingredients we use.

In that context, what's a synonym for "picky" with a positive connotation, that denotes that we care very much about the quality of the ingredients?

- *Selective* lacks emotion.
- *Choicy* is a bit over-the-top.

Drawing a blank here.

I saw the other question about "picky", but the context is not the same:
[Adjective for exclusive/selective/picky with positive connotations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72999/adjective-for-exclusive-selective-picky-with-positive-connotations)

Comment: Unless implied by context, ***particular*** doesn't have the same negative connotations as ***picky***. But to my mind it doesn't necessarily have any particularly positive associations either.

Comment: What about the preposition used, are you committed to 'about' or flexible? Is 'in' acceptable?

Comment: @ermanen: I thought word-choice was for choosing a word from a **selection given in the OP**. Also, there's no supertag for single/compund word requests. Considering that all answers so far are single word, I didn't add a phrase-request tag. It can be added later if we get a good phrase as an answer.

Comment: @ermanen: From the [tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info): Use this tag for questions that are about choosing the best word to fit a particular situation. For a question to be tagged thus, the alternatives to choose from **must be explicitly provided by the question asker**.

Comment: @ermanen: Hmm. I think you should propose it on meta.

Comment: You might bet interested in [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/181861/45432) I wrote a rambling answer on gourmet and antonyms.

Comment: I would use _exacting_, in the sense (given in Merriam-Webster) of "requiring careful attention and precision." An even more apt term (except that most people probably aren't familiar with it is _exigent_, meaning (again per MW) "requiring or calling for much: DEMANDING." Savarin Coffee built a generation of commercials around a character known as "El Exigente—the demanding one," who wandered through the coffee plantations, selecting only the finest beans for the company's coffee.

Comment: I do not see why "selective" is not the right word and what *emotions* have to do with food choices.

Comment: For 'choicy' you say a bit over the top, by which I guess you mean 'not actually a word'?

Answer (score 81):

***[Discerning.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discerning)***

> Having or showing good taste or judgment; discriminating.

Collins English Dictionary, as found at thefreedictionary.com

---

The following would work:

> *"We're discerning about the ingredients that we use."*

However, as pointed out to me in the comments, the more common usage is:

> *"We're discerning **in** the ingredients that we use."*

Comment: Though it is attested, "discerning *about*" isn't the usual phrase, which is "discerning *in*". "We are very discerning in our selection of ingredients." (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(discerning+in)%2C(discerning+about)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28discerning%20in%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28discerning%20about%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 34):

**Selective**

> We are very selective in choosing our ingredients.

2. tending to choose carefully or characterized by careful choice ([Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/selective))

Comment: This works with the OP's sentence better than the others do, and is in the right register.

Comment: In case the OP is considering retaining "about" in his sentence: though *selective *about*" is on the rise, *selective* appears far more often with "in".  "We are *selective* in our choice of ingredients."  (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(selective+in)%2C(selective+about)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28selective%20in%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28selective%20about%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: OP didn't want to use it though.

Comment: Selective is probably the least pretentious word to use from all of these examples.  I believe "Particular" would also be a decent substitute.

Comment: I proposed selective with *fine palate* to connote the food quality aspect.

Answer (score 16):

[**Discriminating**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminating)

> : liking only things that are of good quality : able to recognize the difference between things that are of good quality and those that are not

In the context of being picky about food ingredients, readers *should* understand this meaning and its positive connotation.  However, I worry that semi-literate readers would confuse it with the word **discriminatory**.

Comment: @AndyT I've heard it in the positive sense of "possessing fine judgment or taste".

Answer (score 15):

A word in the same register as *picky* but without the negative connotations that *picky* sometimes has, is *choosy*.

**We're very *choosy* about our ingredients.**

Comment: And just the opposite is true with "choosy" and "about". "Choosy *about*" has long been the form, and "choosy *in*" is on the rise. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(choosy+about)%2C(choosy+in)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28choosy%20about%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28choosy%20in%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: That's almost like picky. :)

Comment: As we say, almost, but not quite. :)

Comment: No need to specify what you're being choosy about. *Choosy moms choose Jif* has been a very successful slogan and ad campaign, and has spawned numerous snowclones, even though those moms clearly aren't choosy with their children's consumption of hydrogenated oils and corn syrup.

Comment: @choster: *snowclone* was a new one for me.

Answer (score 13):

"We're very **conscientious** about the ingredients we use"

> [**conscientious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious) *adjective*: very careful about doing what you are supposed to do: concerned with doing something correctly. (Merriam-Webster online)

Comment: +1. Never heard it in the context of food before, but interesting choice.

Comment: +1. to me, I think conscientious here would sound like they're being picky for ethical reasons though (e.g. like using fair trade bananas) rather than necessarily picky for quality.

Comment: @anotherdave - here at *EL&U* we are very conscientious about providing each highly valued OP with a variety of fine answers imported daily from across the globe. Thank you for expressing your interest. ;-)

Comment: To me, not a native English speaker, conscientious seems more about an activity than about a thing.  So one can be conscientious about choosing ingredients, or conscientious about preparing the ingredients.  But being conscientious about the ingredients themself seems a bit off.

Comment: Well, you seem to be proficient enough, @Taemyr, to find an issue here that more broadly would apply to many of the answers - but that is because of the OP's example sentence, *We're very ___ about the ingredients we use*, which is a vernacular and contracted construction. More formally the sentence would be something like, **"We're very conscientious about the quality of the ingredients we choose to use in our products**"

Answer (score 11):

**[Meticulous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/meticulous)**

> showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise.

They are meticulous when selecting ingredients.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Izaac. This is a good answer. Perhaps you could cite the resource you used to define *meticulous*.

Answer (score 6):

Try **[scrupulous](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/scrupulous)** on for size. It marries Bravo's `selective` with Eva's `conscientious`.

> Scrupulous means very careful to do things properly and correctly (Vocabulary.com)

*"We're very **scrupulous** about the ingredients we use"*

Comment: Our unscrupulous competitors use melamine.

Comment: @TimRomano: Aren't you glad `scrupulous` works with `about` :)

Comment: Don't they make a delightful pair!

Comment: Perhaps because of the connection to "scruples", I think scrupulous implies a moral or ethical dimension to the selectivity.  Being scrupulous about ingredients might involve things like fair trade chocolate.  Ultimately I think this is a narrower use than many of the more upvoted choices.

Comment: @Kirt: Interesting perspective. I still think it's perfect, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Judicious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/judicious)

> ju•di•cious (dʒuˈdɪʃ əs)
>
> adj.
> having, exercising, or characterized by good judgment; discreet, prudent, balanced, or wise: judicious use of one's money; a judicious selection.

May fit in OP's sentence quite well, since it connotes an *active, personal* selection. "Selective" can describe any mechanical filtering process; "judicious" is backed up by human expertise and taste.

Comment: This is a nice answer, could you back it up by citing the source you used for your definition?

Answer (score 2):

*Picky* (Merriam-Webster), as you know, generally has a negative connotation because it is implied that picky individuals are may be generally hard to please, and they may lack static, well-defined standards for being so selective.  As Merriam-Webster puts it in their definition for ***fastidious*** (another word you might consider, though will likely want to reject), they have "capricious standards."  We also often use this word to describe children.  Having said that, a number of other brands have actually "owned" the word "picky," proudly admitting that they are picky about their ingredients, some even going so far as to include the word "picky" in the name of their product.  It sounds like you want to set yourself apart from those brands by using a more mature-sounding word.

For me, the first word that comes to mind that fits this bill is ***discerning***, which user **Okoning** as already graciously suggested; however, with a little thought, a few others came to mind.

#### [Meticulous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Meticulous)

You might consider *meticulous*.  This shows that you are painstaking, precise, and thorough about every detail (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language) when you select your ingredients.  As person who is sometimes inappropriately *meticulous* myself, I may be especially partial to the word.  A quick search of the web shows that some makers of food and cosmetic products are comfortable with this word and already use the exact phrase "meticulously select our ingredients."

#### [Persnickety](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Persnickety)

*Persnickety* can conjure an air of fussiness (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary) and snootiness (Wordnet 3.0) that, depending upon the image you want for your product, may not be a bad thing.  If the word fits the rest of your description, prospective customers may be happy to hear that you care, to a fault, about what goes into your products.

I feel compelled to present a short B-list options as well:

> We're ***zealous*** about the ingredients we use.

On one hand, you may want to show off your unbridled enthusiasm (Collins English Dictionary) for your ingredients.  On the other hand, thanks to the word's informal meanings (The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus), this may make it sound as though, when you receive ingredients that don't meet your standards for freshness, it is company policy to smash the tail lights of the truck that delivered the offending produce.

> We're ***methodical*** about the ingredients we use.

*By itself*, I don't think *methodical* has the punch you are seeking.  If you augment it with "yet X," it might work for you:

> We're *methodical* ***yet passionate*** about the ingredients we use.

or *methodical yet discerning*, etc.
This makes it sound more like you only select an ingredient if it gets a favorable report from your lab coat-wearing, clipboard-toting experts (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language), **and** is declared "finest in the land" or at least "not complete rubbish" by your monocle-and-ascot-sporting aficionado.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, JTL. This is a good answer. Perhaps you could cite the resources you used to define your suggested words.

Answer (score 1):

Gourmand.  Gluttonous but discerningly so.  Not to be used in the absence of excess of gusto.

Finicky.  Not always positive.

Discerning. Usually positive.  (Discerning palate).

Discriminating.  (For those of discriminating taste).

Comment: "Discriminating" is great.  "Discerning" is already in another answer (currently top-voted).  "Finicky" is negative.  "Gourmand" isn't an adjective, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Fastidious. It is a lovely word and an appropriate synonym for "picky".

Comment: It is a lovely word and is a synonym for picky, but the OP specified it should be positive.  Fastidious often implies caring more than is reasonable and is not clearly positive.

Comment: Hi Kit and welcome to ELU! This a great suggestion, but a definition would aid in identifying "fastidious" as a suitable synonym.

Answer (score 1):

It's a noun, but what about [Connoisseur](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/connoisseur)?

> noun
>
> 1. a person who is especially competent to pass critical judgments in an art, particularly one of the fine arts, or in matters of taste: a
>      connoisseur of modern art.
> 2. a discerning judge of the best in any field: a connoisseur of horses.

Maybe something like

```
"When it comes to ingredients, we are quite the connoisseurs".
```

Rewrite according to preferred register and style, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda surprised no one has gone with [Strict](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strict).

Another option is a synonym to the above, [Rigorous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rigorous).

Answer (score 0):

**[Critical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/critical)**

So:

> We are very *critical* of the ingredients we use

It suggests a professionalism, and a lot of time and energy go into selecting ingredients.

Edit to add

The emphasis should be on critical analysis of merits. As per the definition, Expressing or involving an analysis of the **merits** and faults of a work of literature, music, or art:
she never won the critical acclaim she sought

Comment: I don't think this is the right usage of that word.  What I get from your example sentence is that you berate your ingredients!  OTOH you could say "For us, it's critical to use the best ingredients".

Comment: Thanks for explanation of the - 1. As per the definition, Expressing or involving an analysis of the **merits** and faults of a work of literature, music, or art:
she never won the critical acclaim she sought

Comment: I see that definition, and I do appreciate your nice reply, but I still think that the phrase "critical of" always implies criticism of the "negative spoken or written judgment" variety.  I tried a Google search of this phrase in quotes, but the results aren't very helpful -- but FWIW, in the 3 pages of results that I scrolled through, every "snippet" containing this phrase used it in this negative sense.

Comment: Try Google for critical acclaim ;-) and if someone was critical of their own work (in this case, selection of ingredients) it would clearly imply that they're going for quality. however, I appreciate your point, and I've already up voted discerning, as it's clearly the best answer!

Comment: To me it's the word "of" that makes the difference, though I wasn't clear about that in my first comment.  "Critical acclaim" is certainly a positive thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question speaks of **positive connotation** and **food**. I suggest making the phrase therefore positive, and referring to *fine palate* for the notion of food. It is [written](https://books.google.ca/books?id=g5nYBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=fine+palate+meaning&source=bl&ots=8l9x3Um67H&sig=J-dAA923dX9x9vSn6mCKfL0dmOM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fTCZVeq4F8r2-AG3_4OACQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=fine%20palate%20meaning&f=false):

> Food is palatable if it doesn't taste bad, and those with a *fine palate* may frequent the more expensive restaurants.

Tying in the *selective* notion, I would write:

> We **select** our ingredients using a **fine palate**.

Comment: Edited after downvote sans comment. Little help?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of :

1) Meticulous
taking or showing extreme care about minute details.

2) Precise
exact in measuring, recording, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The classic formulation is "all ingredients are carefully selected".

Answer (score -1):

We **whole-heartedly follow our epicurean sensibilities when selecting** the ingredients we use.

Comment: The question asks for a synonym, which will preclude a sentence-long description.

Comment: Thew word *epicurean* would work, David.  Perhaps you could cite the resource you use to define *epicurean*, and edit your sentence so that it resembles the OP a little more closely.